# Are the Title-bar and Menu-bar included when getting a Form's preferredHeight?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, menubar

When we write `int h = myForm.getPreferredH();` does the `h` variable contains the height of the `Title-bar` and the height of the `Menu-bar` ? In the appropriate how to get the Title-bar's (preferred) height and the Menu-bar's (preferred) height ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will include the preferred height of the entire form including everything. That value is useless though, there is no sense in extracting it and LWUIT completely ignores it.